# How to get access to Angular object in a Protractor test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor

I'm trying to load [$httpBackend](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ngMockE2E/service/$httpBackend) in a Protractor test.  The very first thing the documentation says to do is set up an `angular.module` in the test.  However, I have no reference to `angular` inside my tests.

I tried merely `console.log`ing `angular`.  I tried [`browser.driver.window`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.Options.prototype.window) and [`browser.driver.Window`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.Window) but was unable to get ahold of either.  I also tried just `require('angular')` in my protractor `.spec.js` files.

[This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29377619/how-to-switch-between-httpbackendmocks-in-protractor-test) also seems to simply assume access will be there.

I can't find any references to $httpBackend in [angular/protractor in github](https://github.com/angular/protractor/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%24httpBackend) either (except for the one in the unit test).

Running out of ideas about how to go about setting this up.

Answer (score 1):

This link [angular/protractor in github](https://github.com/angular/protractor/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%24httpBackend) is to protractor's unit test.
U can't inject angular services in protractor because it's end2end test framework.

There you don't inject anything. That's why You don't need even have to have this tests in the same place where your project.

Comment: If you look at https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ngMockE2E/service/$httpBackend, it is specifically talking about how to use `$httpBackend` in an end-to-end test, not a unit test.

Comment: You can use this ngMockE2E with $httpBackend to prepare fake backend for your tests. But like I said, end 2 end tests doesn't inject any application dependencies and doesn't change how it works. They just affect on UI and observe how are changes.

Comment: Please see this video from AngularConf 2014 that shows Angular being accessed within Protractor to help run tests: https://youtu.be/aQipuiTcn3U?t=955

Comment: Im actually looking for an answer, and @diplosaurus is right, the video shows how they are actually using the angular inside of it.